# Data.table join using 'on' when column names contain spaces

Tags: r, data.table

Can a non-equi join be done using the "on" argument in data.table when one or more column names contain spaces?

I understand that syntactically invalid names should be avoided and can be corrected (e.g., [How to deal with spaces in column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744282/how-to-deal-with-spaces-in-column-names)) but beyond that, wrapping in backticks doesn't seem to work in data.table `on` argument.

For example, to perform a non-equi join of the two tables below:

```
library(data.table) 

dt1 <- data.table(x = c("a", "b", "c"), y = c(2, 1, 3))

dt2 <- data.table(z = c("r", "g", "b"),
                  "y min" = seq(0.9, 2.9, 1), 
                  "y max" = seq(1.1, 3.1, 1))

#join dt1 and dt2 where y is in the range ('y min', 'y max')
dt1[dt2, on = .(y >= `y min`, y <= `y max`), z := i.z]
```

Fails with

```
##Error in `[.data.table`(dt1, dt2, on = .(y >= `y min`, y <= `y max`),  : 
##  Column(s) [`y min`,`y max`] not found in i
```

Desired output (made by same join with syntactically valid names):

```
dt1[dt2, on = .(y >= ymin, y <= ymax), z := i.z]
##> dt1
##   x y z
##1: a 2 g
##2: b 1 r
##3: c 3 b
```

Comment: Try `dt1[dt2, on = c("y>=y min", "y<=y max"), z := i.z]`

Comment: That works, thanks. I had tried this construct, but included white space around the operators (`c("y> = y min", "y <= y max")`). Frank's linked answer was helpful in seeing that point, which I haven't run across in the data.table documentation.